# CMake Visual Studio Generator Expression RelWithDebInfo

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am using a external library in my project and I need to to copy a dll next to the exe during the build process.  The debug and release dll's are named the same and are in a "Debug" and "Release" directory.

Building with visual studio.

This is what I have right now:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET App POST_BUILD       
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different   
        ${api}/lib/x64/$<CONFIG>/libfbxsdk.dll     
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:App>)
```

But this fails for RelWithDebInfo - how do I copy the Debug dll to the Debug directory and the Release dll to the Release and RelWithDebInfo directory?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using...

```
add_custom_command(TARGET App POST_BUILD       
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different   
        ${fbxroot}/lib/x64/$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:Release>$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:$<CONFIG>>/libfbxsdk.dll     
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:App>)
```

which seems to be working.